# Cannot start debug in Gogland 1.0 EAP on macOS Sierra

Tags: go, macos-sierra, goland

I've switched to Go not so long ago. I've chosen JetBrains Gogland as IDE. I like both: Go and IDE, except a one issue. I don't know whether it is an issue with IDE or with Go lang configuration on macOS Sierra. But when I'm trying start debuging for a test from Gogland, the build fails with message:

```
GOROOT=/usr/local/go
GOPATH=/Users/username/project/go
/usr/local/go/bin/go test -c -i -o /private/var/folders/3b/hlrss45s1p93cgtq9xgsw4gh0000gn/T/All_in__bitbucket_org_ username_package_matrix_go -gcflags "-N -l" -a bitbucket.org/usaername/package/matrix
go install runtime/internal/sys: open /usr/local/go/pkg/darwin_amd64/runtime/internal/sys.a: permission denied
```

I use Go 1.9

```
$ go version
go version go1.9 darwin/amd64
$ go env
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/azagretdinov/project/go"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.9/libexec"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.9/libexec/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
CC="clang"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/var/folders/3b/hlrss45s1p93cgtq9xgsw4gh0000gn/T/go-build006508560=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -fno-common"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
```

Information about Gogland

```
Gogland (1.0 Preview) 1.0 EAP
Build #GO-172.3757.46, built on August 11, 2017
Gogland EAP User
Expiration date: November 9, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-915-b10 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Mac OS X 10.12.6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using an old version of the IDE, please upgrade to the latest one and it will work as expected.

For reference, this issue was addressed in EAP 13 / 14 (which is the latest), see the original issue here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GO-4430

Comment: Thank for answer! I was thinking that I used up-date version, because JetBrains Tool showed me that everything was updated. But when I double-checked, I found out that I started previous version instead the latest.